# dynamical memory allocation and return value 3221225477

Tags: c

I am doing my homework, the problem is as follows:

1. accept words separated by commas.
2. extracted each word and reverse them.
3. put them back in order.

for example, if I enter "apple,egg", I get "elppa,gge"

So far I've completed most of the program, the program works well when I enter less than four words, but with more than four words such as "ybur,etaga,etiluzal,iluzal sipal,etihcalam" the program doesn't work and it shows me return value 3221225477.
I just learned how to use dynamical memory allocation so I think it may result from the fact that I did not use it properly, if that's true, please correct me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c=1,i,s;
    char a[1000];
    fgets(a,1000,stdin);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        if(a[i]=='\n'){
            a[i]='\0';
        }
    } 
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        if(a[i]==','){
            c++;
        }
    }
    char **b;
    b=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*c); 
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        b[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    }
    strcpy(b[0],strtok(a,","));
    for(i=1;i<c;i++){
        strcpy(b[i],strtok(NULL,","));
    }
    char **d;
    d=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*c);
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        d[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(b[i]));
        for(s=0;s<strlen(b[i]);s++){
            d[i][s]=b[i][strlen(b[i])-s-1];
        }
    }
    printf("%s",d[0]);
    for(i=1;i<c;i++){
        printf(",%s",d[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<c;i++){
        free(b[i]);
        free(d[i]);
    }
    free(b);
    free(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that the program works no matter what words I enter.

Comment: You could be accessing a memory location that you shouldnt be which is why you are getting a memory address instead of a string.

Comment: 3221225477 is 0xC0000005.  That's a well known Windows error code

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){` and similar statements:  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`  (aka unsigned long int)  comparing that unsigned value to a signed variable, like 'i' is error prone,  Suggest the 'i' be declared like:  `size_t i;`

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `b=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*c);`   1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest removing that cast.  2) the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the c standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" )`

Comment: @user3629249 thank you very much, I'm new to programming and thus are not familiar with that kind of knowledge. where can I read things like that?

Comment: The easiest way to learn the details of the C library functions that you use is to read/understand the MAN page for each of those functions and then always check for an error when calling any of the C library functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*c);
```

should be

```
b = malloc(sizeof(char *) * c); 
                       ^--------------(sizeof pointer)
```

As of now you are only allocating `sizeof char * c` to `char **` as it should be `sizeof pointer * c`.

Also you don't need to cast the malloc return.

Comment: I didn't notice that I made such a stupid mistake....Thank you.

Comment: @FunCry That's okay.

Comment: And I want to know why I don't need to cast the malloc return. Is it because that I return it at the end of the program?

Comment: @FunCry Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @FunCry: A quiet save pattern to always get the right size is to do: `char ** b = malloc(c * sizeof *b);` No specification of a type is needed. Please note that `sizeof` is an operator and not a function, so if used with a variable there is *no* need to enclose the variable into parenthesis.